# Why did Mikoto Suoh allow himself to be captured?

Tags: k-project

In episode 1 of *K-Project*, Mikoto Suoh of the red clan allows himself to be captured during a confrontation with the blue clan.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He willingly put himself in that position to have a private dialogue with the Blue King about the whereabouts of the gray king who killed his clan-mate.

Since they are Kings and of opposite factions they couldn't just sit down and chat without a fight. Suoh was also in major danger of causing a Damocles Down event due the deterioration of his sword.

He felt more at peace in the Blue King's captivity because the two of them share a long history and he knew that if calamity struck the Blue King would not let him cause disaster.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't recall such a chat being shown on screen. Was it ever alluded to in the show?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was in the second or third episode. The blue King talked to him while he was in his cell

Comment: I am pretty sure there was a bit of talk about how he might have also turned himself in to get some kind of rest or reassurance. His sword was deteriorating, and could soon spell a Damocles down disaster. Something about getting peaceful rest or having the blue king nearby to kill him to prevent the disaster if it got that far. I am not completely sure, It has been a while since I saw the series.

Comment: Ok, Kaz. The only thing that bothers me is how tired and unresponsive he seemed during the prison encounter with the blue king. If he had gone in with the intention to procure information, wouldn't he have taken a more active role in initiating conversation? His unconcern seems to support Ryan's answer. Also, I hope Ryan is correct because it would be more poetic and in line with Mikoto's character. @Ryan, if you post that as an answer before tomorrow I'll accept it; otherwise I'll accept this one.

Comment: @user404789 I took Ryan's comment into account after viewing some old scenes. It is now edited into my answer with proper referrence.

Comment: @KazRodgers I like the edit! I was also rewatching some scenes today, and I stumbled upon the bar meeting between Kusanagi and Seri Awashima, where Kusanagi proposes that Mikoto might have arranged for his arrest so the blue king could intervene if things went downhill. I completely overlooked that the first time through!

Answer (score 0):

He allowed himself to be captured because he knew the Blue King, Resei Munakata, wouldn't let any disaster happen, and if it did, he would try to fix it immediately.

He also didn't want to have to fight anyone, or draw any more power from his slate, because of the bad shape his Sword of Damocles was in. Mikoto wanted to get some rest in the custody of Septer 4 so he wouldn't worry about getting over worked, or getting so angry he destroys everything around him.